# Data Sources for 7-day new Corona cases per Capita

Tags: germany, covid-19

Many German *Länder* are currently setting quarantine requirements for arriving travelers based on whether or not the number of new COVID-19 cases over the previous 7 days exceeds 50 per 100 000 people for the traveller’s origin. There are many advantages to this metric, however one of the disadvantages is that it is very hard to find data sources that easily identify whether or not a given country meets this criteria. What are some data sources which compile this information in this way?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter what the actual numbers are, nor what is reported in the locale, but what each *Land* accepts as an authority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Berlin newspaper **Morgenpost** offers a nice site (in German), with all relevant information - both as a **map** but also as text data.

To find the amount of cases, in the last 7 days per 1000.000 for a specific country, you have to select:

- Europe or World wide
- Daily cases
- Cases per 100.000

---

Floating buttons are at the top with 3 offers:

- Germany (Deutschland)

  - Which will list the results by states

    - The map will show other countries with regional information when available

      - Canada, Italy, and US
- Europe (Europa)

  - Which will list all countries in Europe
- Worldwide (weltweit)

  - Which will list all countries

---

Under the floating buttons, below the map, the selected **area** and **date** are shown with a summary:

- Confirmed (bestätigt)
- Recovered (wieder gesund)
- Deaths (Totesfälle)

---

Under the summary, you can select

- Total cases (Gesamt-Fallzahlen)
- **Daily cases** (Neuinfektionen)

---

The detailed information is stored in 2 tabs

- Case numbers (Fälle)

  - Showing: Confirmed, Recovered, Death, and tendency
- **Cases per 100.000** (pro 100.000 EW)

  - Showing: **last 7 days**, daily and tendency

---

At the bottom, you can select a **date**

- The image below shows 2020-03-26

Switzerland (Schweiz) had 92 cases per 100.000 in the last 7 days and 13 on the selected date.

---

[image: Morgenpost 26.03.2020]

---

**Sources**:

- [Corona: Echtzeit-Karte zeigt Fallzahlen und Neuinfektionen in Deutschland und weltweit](https://interaktiv.morgenpost.de/corona-virus-karte-infektionen-deutschland-weltweit/)

Answer (score 2):

For EU/EEA/UK/Switzerland (countries to which the 50-per-100000 requirement applies), the Robert Koch Institute (the federal public health agency) publishes a map [here](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Quarantaene_Einreisen_Deutschland.html).

Entry from other countries is subject to 14-day isolation regardless of incidence rate.

Comment: [Courts in NRW ruled that it isn't consitutional to apply isolation requirements regardless of incident rates](https://www.lto.de/recht/nachrichten/n/ovg-nrw-13b77620ne-quarantaene-pflicht-nach-einreise-aus-drittland-ausser-vollzug-nordrhein-westfalen-corona-verordnung-reise/) and so now (at least for NRW) the 50-per-100000 requirement is applied equally to all countries worldwide.

Answer (score 1):

Worldometer.com

You may have to copy data into a spreadsheet to compute measures/ratios they don't show.