# Is there a graphic of COVID-19 cases per 100,000 people over 14 days which also indicates past values of this ratio?

Tags: covid-19, maps

As many European countries (Norway, Finland, Estonia, Latvia, etc) have travel restrictions that depend on the number of confirmed cases per 100,000 people over the last 14 days, I'm wondering if there's a map of how this value has changed anywhere. To clarify the previous, this is, in other words, a map of how travel restrictions in Europe are changing from day to day based on local regulations—as well as what travel is permissible without restrictions.

There are several *current* maps (or similar) of the 'cases per 100,000 people over 14 days' indicator:

- [Estonian daily-updating map at Delfi.ee](https://www.delfi.ee/news/paevauudised/valismaa/suur-graafik-millistes-maailma-riikides-on-koroonaviirus-kontrolli-all-ehk-kust-eestisse-tulles-pole-karantiin-vajalik?id=90015879);
- [Norway has a bi-weekly pass/test map](https://www.fhi.no/en/op/novel-coronavirus-facts-advice/facts-and-general-advice/travel-advice-COVID19/) of their travel restrictions' criteria;
- [OurWorldInData.org](https://ourworldindata.org/covid-cases) has a ["Daily confirmed COVID-19 cases per million people" map](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/new-covid-cases-per-million?year=latest) which also has a "Change over time" option, *but* this change over time isn't averaged over the last 14 days.

The last of these is referenced to ECDC data, but ECDC only provides [data tables](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/publications-data/data-national-14-day-notification-rate-covid-19) without graphic—and the notice on that page says it's updated weekly, not daily.

**Is there a graphic of COVID-19 cases per 100,000 people over 14 days which also indicates past values of this ratio?**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to fit the travel specs as per the [help]. Sorry.

Comment: Possibly somewhere on the Robert Koch Institut site? https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Quarantaene_Einreisen_Deutschland.html

Comment: @gktscrk FWIW, I think this is a valid question and the answer would be of interest to many travellers eg those looking to book at short notice and wanting to see an indication of the infection rate trajectory to help inform their decision

Comment: @Traveller: That's exactly what I wanted to use it for :) I looked at RKI and I think Germany uses them as the primary source of data. Regrettably, their English pages seem more limited and my German isn't good enough to track down whether there's something suitable there.

Comment: Similar to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157632/data-sources-for-7-day-new-corona-cases-per-capita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [ECDC website](https://qap.ecdc.europa.eu/public/extensions/COVID-19/COVID-19.html), go to "Country comparison" and select the countries you want. Then, on the first graph, choose "14-day cumulative (log)":

[image: graph of the 14-day incidence of three countries over time]

The numbers there seem to be in accordance with what the news says. Note that Germany uses the number of new cases in the **last 7 days** per 100000 inhabitants to decide which areas are risk areas. A value over 50 of the 7-day incidence (approximately a value of 100 of the 14-day incidence statistic) means a risk area.